# how can i add an app widget to home screen automatically?

Tags: android, widget, badge

I have searched many results from GOOGLE, only find to do this is to use app widget. After I learned how to write a widget, but a new problem appeared. How can I add an app widget to home screen automatically? Why some third party app can do this? I just confused about it. Is anyone can help me to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add widgets programatically to home screen. But you can create a widget host yourself and let user add widgets to that.